# Создание архива с добавлением туда директории со всеми файлами внутри

Tags: c++, zip, архивация

Хочу создать архив и засунуть туда каталог со всеми файлами и подкаталогами, для дальнейшей транспортировки.
Какие библиотеки для работы с архивами посоветуете ? Желательно с примерами.

Comment: zlib (15 символов). https://eax.me/zlib/

Comment: Владимир, в предоставленном примере показана архивация одного файла.

Comment: А по вашему архивация двух файлов будет отличатся сильно? Если на принимающей стороне ваш софт - храните в этом архиве файлы как вам нравится.